# Evaluating $\limsup_{n\to \infty}\;(\,2n(2n+1)\,)^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Could someone suggest a way to calculate the following lim?

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\;(\,2n(2n+1)\,)^{1/n}$$

Edit: I was told by someone it's 1 but didn't find a way to prove it

Comment: Is there anything you have tried so far and is there anything in particular that you're struggling to do?

Comment: @OliverClarke I tried using a(n+1)/a(n) but that didn't work

Comment: Can you calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}$?

Comment: @saulspatz yes it's 1

Comment: Can you see how to use that to solve this problem?

Comment: solved it, thanks! but how you though about this?

Answer (score 1):

As written in the previous answer, $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a^{1/n}
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}
=1$$ for $a>0.$
Moreover, $2n+1=n(2+1/n).$

Then 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(2n(2n+1))^{1/n}=
 \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}2^{1/n}n^{1/n}n^{1/n}(2+1/n)^{1/n}=1$$

As the limit exists, limsup is equal to the limit.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is
$\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{1/n}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}
=1
$
for any $a > 0$.

The second is harder
(and implies the first),
so I'll give my standard
somewhat magic proof.

Bernoulli's equality states that
$(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx$
for $n \ge 1, x \ge 0$.

Then
$(1+1/\sqrt{n})^n
\ge 1+n/\sqrt{n}
\gt \sqrt{n}
=n^{1/2}$.
Raising to the
$2/n$ power,
$n^{1/n}
\lt (1+1/\sqrt{n})^2
=1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1{n}
\le 1+\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}}
$.

Since $n^{1/n} > 1$,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{1/n} = 1$.